# Can I use libman with my SharePoint Add-In project?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, asp.net

I've noticed that libman is only available in Visual Studio 2017 asp.net projects. However, SharePoint Online Add-In projects are also web projects and use lots of javascript libraries. Is there any way to use libman with them?

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way so I am using npm to bring in packages to the same directory as my project and then I am manually including the right js files into my Scripts folder.